# Scroll to a specified div ONLY in bootstrap using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am using simple Javascript to automatically scroll to a specific div within a page utilizing bootstrap.

```
$("button").click(function(){
 $('html,body').animate({
scrollTop:$(".*specific div*").offset().top},
'slow')
 });
```

It works like a charm for the first button, but the script seems to continue on and scroll to every specified div that the script directs toward. Is there any way to cause the script to go to only scroll to each specified div?

Thanks.

Comment: Use id of that specific div

Comment: What Sreenath said.  Don't use classes, use ids and you should get the result you are looking for.

Comment: You can give a unique id to each div, and use the div id in selection `#divId` for scroll to focus.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if i understand your question this is what you can do use anchor tag and add specfic div's id in href attribut

```
<a class="class-for-all-a" href="#about">About</a>

<div id="about"></div>

$('.class-for-all-a').click(function (event){
 event.preventDefault();
 var full_url = this.href;
 var parts = full_url.split("#");
 var trgt = parts[1];
 scrollTop:$("'#' + trgt").offset().top},'slow');
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer Altaf Hussain!

The comments on the original question were enough for the buttons to enact what I wanted down to the t. However, your answer (after googling around to fully understand how this script worked) was much more thorough in its entirety. Thank you for taking the time to answer!